# Can't get XCode 3.2.2 to generate dSYM file

Tags: xcode, debugging, release, symbols, debug-symbols

I have followed the Apple instructions [here](http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/symbolizingcrashdumps.html) to unsuccessfully generate a dSYM file for my release build, I have tried all sorts of settings and its not generating anything, this is for a 32-bit universal Mac OSX application (I'm using the 10.6 SDK and deploying for 10.2).

The even more frustrating thing is I also do iPhone development and am using the EXACT same project settings (relating to symbols and debugging) and it generates a dSYM file just fine!  About the only thing I have read that might be causing the problem is ZeroLink, but I don't think its supported in XCode 3.2.2 anymore?  I can't find it anywhere in the build settings or under the build menu.

Does anyone have any suggestions or know what settings I need to be changing? Thank you for any help!

Current Settings

```
Deployment Postprocessing   YES
Strip Linked Product    YES
Generate Debug Symbols  YES
Debug Information Format    DWARF with dSYM File
Use Separate Strip      YES
Strip Debug Symbols During Copy     NO
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you probably have setup your project for `dSYM` with that [reference here](http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/symbolizingcrashdumps.html).

From what you've showed us, everything looks fine and I use those exact setting inside my current project.

However, I ran into some problems before make it works. I use a midware tool to generate my XCode project and it was actually writing parameters inside`Other Linker Flags` settings. [This can be a reference](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) if you need to find out what are those parameters if present.

Because I don't think you have any special flags there, the other option would be to create an empty project for an iOS application and compare the settings. You said that you actually use the EXACT same setting that the MAC OSX build, but I think it might needs different ones for iOS.

If this still doesn't fix the problem, I think you will have to paste the full project settings in here.

Answer (score 0):

You're not clear on whether you are putting the settings in the project or the target.  Remember that target settings override project settings.

Comment: Oh you gave me hope... but alas my target settings are the same as my project settings :(  Another piece of info I have is I tried setting Strip Linked Product and Use Separate Strip both to NO, and my exe did grow by about 600KB, meaning the debug symbols were probably in there, but it still didn't generate the dSYM file.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that you dont have a build script removing the dysm file.